# c# mvc: how to join Generic View with TextBoxFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to make a view template which who will be used in a few controllers. 
I think about a join generic view with `@Html.TextBoxFor()`. Is possible to do that?

If I have a view standard View:

```
@model Person
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Person", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "iUG2" }))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor( x=>x.name )
   @Html.TextBoxFor( X=>x.surname )
}

@model Address
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Address", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "iUG2" }))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor( x=>x.Street )
   @Html.TextBoxFor( X=>x.City )
}
```

how to transform on generic view?

```
class Tab
{
   public string Method { get; set; }
   public string Controller { get; set; }
}

@model <T>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm( ViewBag.Tab.Method, ViewBag.Tab.Controller, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "iUG2" }))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor( x=>T.?? )
   @Html.TextBoxFor( X=>T.?? )
}
```

If I use generic type, `@Html.BeginForm()` will it still work?

Comment: Most likely, you would need some sort of base model, and make it generic as opposed to just an "anything" model declaration on your page. So your `Tab` class is a good starting point. Try expanding that.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really setup for that. You'll probably need to do multiple `if`s to make this work... this is untested:

```
@model <T>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm( ViewBag.Tab.Method, ViewBag.Tab.Controller, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "iUG2" }))
{
   if (Model is Person)
   {
       @Html.TextBox("Name")
       @Html.TextBox("Surname")
   }
   if (Model is Address)
   {
       @Html.TextBox("Street")
       @Html.TextBox("City")
   }
}
```

Having said that, this is pretty poor design, I suggest you find a way to not use a generic model.